# Cannot find pnputil /disable-device on my windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I am trying to run `pnputil /disable-device` on my windows 10 machine but when I type `pnputil /?` below is what it gets. Any idea how I can find `pnputil /disable-device`?

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

PNPUTIL [/add-driver <...> | /delete-driver <...> |
         /export-driver <...> | /enum-drivers | /?]

Commands:

  /add-driver <filename.inf | *.inf> [/subdirs] [/install]

    Add driver package(s) into the driver store.
      /subdirs - traverse sub directories for driver packages.
      /install - install/update drivers on any matching devices.

  /delete-driver <oem#.inf> [/force]

    Delete driver package from the driver store.
      /force - delete driver package even when it is in use by devices.

  /export-driver <oem#.inf | *> <target directory>

    Export driver package(s) from the driver store into a target directory.

  /enum-drivers

    Enumerate all 3rd party driver packages in the driver store.

  /?

    Show this usage screen.

Legacy Commands:

  [-i] -a <filename.inf> ==> /add-driver <filename.inf> [/install]
  [-f] -d <oem#.inf>     ==> /delete-driver <oem#.inf> [/force]
  -e                     ==> /enum-drivers

Examples:

  pnputil /add-driver x:\driver.inf       <- Add driver package
  pnputil /add-driver c:\oem\*.inf        <- Add multiple driver packages
  pnputil /add-driver device.inf /install <- Add and install driver package
  pnputil /enum-drivers                   <- Enumerate OEM driver packages
  pnputil /delete-driver oem0.inf         <- Delete driver package
  pnputil /delete-driver oem1.inf /force  <- Force delete driver package
  pnputil /export-driver oem6.inf .       <- Export driver package
  pnputil /export-driver * c:\backup      <- Export all driver packages
```

Comment: Curious indeed.  Have you tried `where pnputil` to ensure that you are getting the correct one?

Comment: Why not just disable this on your router?   Then it is for all devices. This is how I disable UnPnP

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Here is the output of `where pnputil` - > `C:\Windows\System32\pnputil.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue. I found that all of the options are available in Win10 Enterprise Version 21H2 but only the options shown in the original post are available in another system running Win10 Enterprise Version 1607. Looks like pnputil got updated somewhere between those versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did `pnputil /? >tmp.txt` and examined the output.

Here is one section of it :

```
/disable-device <instance ID> [/reboot]

  Disable devices on the system.
    /reboot - reboot system if needed to complete the operation.

  Examples:
    Disable device:
      pnputil /disable-device "USB\VID_045E&PID_00DB\6&870CE29&0&1"
```

So it's still there for me.

As one explanation for the fact that you are missing some option
I found in the post
[W10 PNPUTIL Missing options](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/pawg4j/w10_pnputil_missing_options/):

> When I run pnputil on this home edition version it is missing about half its options. The only options available are to install, remove and export drivers and enumeration. It doesn't have any of the start, stop, restart, scan etc commands available.

If your Windows version is Home, this could also be the
explanation for you.

Otherwise, your Windows version is corrupted and you could try:

- Running
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
- Running
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
- And the last before full reinstall
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I was assuming that the output he put in the question was complete.  I too checked mine before I commented and there it was.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I have completed more my answer.

Comment: @harrymc the output of `pnputil /? >tmp.txt` gave the same result as in my questions. The windows version is Windows 10 enterprise 2016 LTSB. Any advice?

Comment: Something is wrong with your Windows version. Besides the 3 points at the end of my answer, is there anything special about your version and its history?